# Showing Existence of Epsilon for Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, heat-equation

I've been given an outline to prove the maximum principle for the heat equation with the growth condition $|u(x,t)| \le Ae^{\alpha|x|^2}$. The first step is to show:

> If $T$ is small such that 
>   $$4\alpha T<1$$
>   Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that
>   $$4\alpha (T+\epsilon)<1$$

I don't know where to begin because this sounds impossible. Wouldn't you get

$$4\alpha (T+\epsilon)<1+4\alpha \epsilon$$

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A := 1 - 4\alpha T > 0$, then take $\epsilon > 0$ small enough such that 
$A - 4\alpha\epsilon > 0$ and you'll have your result. (Edit: Take, for instance, any $0 < \epsilon < \frac{A}{8\alpha}$).

Comment: do you mean $0<\epsilon<\frac{A}{4\alpha}$? thanks so much!

Comment: This also works with $0 < \epsilon < \frac{A}{4\alpha}$. There was no special reason to choose $0 < \epsilon < \frac{A}{8\alpha}$.